# dos command delete folder and files using a wild card character

Tags: batch-file, dos

In a DOS batch command window, I want to delete folders (and corresponding files within that directory) with part of the name that contains the following string (SUB

I want to start at a specfic root directory called C:\app2\proc.

I want to delete the directory and the files contained within the directory.

I want to delete folders where part of the file name is (SUB.
What I have tried so far does not work.

Here is what I have tried to far:

```
del /f /s /q C:\app2\proc\*(SUB*
```

Note: the asterik before (SUB and the asterik after (SUB is not showing up in the display of what I have tried to far.
Thus can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is PowerShell an option for you?

Comment: I made an edit to try to show your command properly.  Is that correct?

Comment: Powershell is not an option that I am aware of. This is the first time that I ever wrote a dos prompt command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to run through your files and send a variable (%x in this case) to `rmdir` with your path.  Try this:

```
for /d %x in (*(sub*) do rmdir /s /q c:\app2\proc\%x
```

Comment: I just tried the following statment for /d %x in (*(sub*) do rmdir /s /q c:\app2\proc\%x and nothing was deleted. I got no response from the dos window

Comment: Sorry, make sure that you're in the c:\app2\proc directory when you run it.

Comment: I tried for /d %x in (*^(sub*) do rmdir /s /q c:\app2\proc\%x with the ^( with the escape character and that did not work. What do you think I should try now?

Comment: I got it to work without escaping anything.  Simply matching on a pattern of "(*(sub)" worked.  Can you give me an example of a directory name (under proc) that should be matched/deleted by this command?

Comment: I went to the highest level directory for the files exist and ran the command with the result directory path showing in the window like the fiollowing: C:\SS_Data\TIQ2>for /d %x in (*(sub*) do rmdir /s /q C:\SS_Data\TIQ2\%x. this did not work. The exact name of the directory path is C:\SS_Data\TIQ2.  An example of I file and folder I want to delete look like the following: C:\SS_Data\TIQ2\01-10-2013\Companyname(SUB12345678901234567).

Comment: When I use the following command: for /d %x in (*(sub*) do rmdir /s /q C:\SS_Data\TIQ2\01-10-2013\%x, I get a response back from dos saying 'The system cannot find the file specified'. When this message shows up, it is under each directory I want to delete. Thus there must be something wrong with the wildcard looking for a file where part of the name is (SUB or even SUB. Thus can you tell me what you would try next? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you're at the point where we can no longer do it in one line.  I'm thinking you can put the above command in a .bat file (% signs need to be doubled %% in a bat file) and write another .bat file to rip through all the directories in c:\SS_Data\TIQ2 and call the original .bat file with the dated-directory as a parameter.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could write this kind of code?

Answer (score 0):

You porbably need to escape that ( character so that it does not get evaluated.

Checkout http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php it seems you should replace ( with ^(

Comment: I should also mention that after the file strucutre of           c:\app2\proc there is a daily folder structure that is 01-08-2013. In other words the format includes a saily mm-dd-yyyy month-day-year format.